# Client company wants Firestore data hidden from developers

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

We are developing a mobile application with a Firebase backend for a client organization. They want their organization's data hidden from the developer team. The firebase database is used by a flutter mobile application.

My current idea is to develop the app in an entirely different google account, and to swap configuration to clients google account when deploying, and deploy the cloud functions under their supervision. But there must be a easier way!

Can you guys suggest an elegant way to achieve this data privacy requirement of the clients?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want here is to utilize [IAM roles](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/iam/overview) in the project to restrict access. The client can own the project and grant limited access to the developers through [roles](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/iam/roles) that can be assigned.

They could give permission to deploy cloud functions without being able to read the entire Firestore database, as an example.

I'd recommend creating a second staging or "non-production" project that developers have full access to as well, since developing when you can't use the Firestore data viewer or have admin read access can be very difficult.